# Extend Table with extra properties when type property is X

Tags: database, entity-framework, database-design

Two years ago I created a web application using Entity Framework. In this application the client tracks the projects they did for their clients.

Now they want an update of the application to add some new project types. These new types will have some extra data to be stored.

So at this moment a project has a type, start and end date, description,... that are stored in the database. But now these new types need some extra properties.

What is the best approach to extend the current database?

These new properties will only be used when the project is one of the new types. The existing properties (date, description, ...) are shared between all types.

What are the possible solutions when using Entity Framework?

**EDIT:**
The extra properties will be foreign keys to another table.
Example: Project of type A will have a picture attached to it(stored in another table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can do one of two things:

**(1)** create a new table linked to the existing table that holds those new properties

or

**(2)** just simply add those new properties to the existing table (all must be nullable, in that case, since they don't have any values for the existing project types)

**Option #1** is beneficial since in that new extra table, you can define those new columns as nullable or not nullable (as required by your business rules). But the downside is that for those new project types, your data is now split up over two tables which you'd need to join in those cases to get all the information.

Depending on which version of .NET and thus the Entity Framework you're using, you could probably hide much of that effort behind a mapping of and old and a new project type to one or two tables ([something like shown in this blog post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj715646.aspx)).

**Option #2** is quicker, more obvious - and all data is still stored in the one, common table. But since the old project types don't have those new values, all your new columns must be nullable - which might not fit well to your business requirements.

Comment: And which sollution has your preference?
The extra properties will be foreign keys to other tables so I think option (1) will make more sense.

Comment: @Beejee: if those really are all just FK links to other tables, then I'd just option #2 - for the "old" project types, they'll just be NULL (no link)

Comment: Yeah i meant option 2. I switched the numbers.